# EC2 CPU Spikes in CloudWatch, but not within the VM

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch

During the past couple of weeks, a couple of my server instances keep triggering CloudWatch alarms that I've set for CPU usage.

I can see periodic 1min spikes in CloudWatch only within the EC2 CPUUtilization metric. I cannot see them on the instance itself using top, atop, CloudWatch Agent, etc.

I cannot find any correlation or corroborating measurement inside the VM to these events.

I've searched and read documentation and come up empty handed.

Any thoughts?

At the moment, I'm confident that the deployed app code is behaving. Am I wrong to think that CloudWatch is showing artifacts of something I don't have visibility into?... on only two instances? If it happened across the autoscaling group, I'd probably write this off as some kind of background noise.

Comment: What instance class are you on - T2's are credit based. Also ec2 are vm's so share the physical hardware - could it be a "noisy neighbour"?

Comment: I'm currently on c5.large w/ no observable CPU steal. Could a noisy neighbor really leak across non-T* instances?